# How do I loop multiple scripts in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, button, colors

I have some code here and I want the squares to go blue, green, indigo then go back to the beginning. Each time I click the button the colour will change. The code here goes blue, green, indigo and then changes between indigo and black while I want it to go to blue again. Is there a way of restarting the entire code again?

```
<--code for animated squares!-->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
#container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  background: Black;
}
div#animate {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 175px;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: Blue;
}
</style>

<style>
#containertwo {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  background: Black;
}
div#animatetwo {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 175px;
  top: 175px;
  background-color: Black;
}
</style>
<body>

<style>
#containerthree {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  background: Black;
}
div#animatethree {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 175px;
  top: 350px;
  background-color: Black;
}
</style>

<body>

<p>
<button onClick="button_click();button_clicktwo();button_clickthree()">Change Colour</button>
</p>

<div id ="container">
<div id ="animate"></div>
<div id ="animatetwo"></div>
<div id ="animatethree"></div>
</div>

<div id="box" onClick="button_click(j)();"></div>
<script>
var colors = ["Black","Black","Blue"];
function button_click() {
    var box = document.getElementById("animate");
    var background_color = box.style.backgroundColor;
    var i = colors.indexOf(background_color);
    if (i === colors.length-1) {
        i = -1;
    }
    animate.style.backgroundColor = colors[i+1];
}
</script>

<div id="box" onClick="button_clicktwo();"></div>
<script>
var colorstwo = ["Green","Black","Black",];
function button_clicktwo() {
    var box = document.getElementById("animatetwo");
    var background_color = box.style.backgroundColor;
    var i = colorstwo.indexOf(background_color);
    if (i === colorstwo.length-1) {
        i = -1;
    }
    animatetwo.style.backgroundColor = colorstwo[i+1];
}
</script>

<div id="box" onClick="button_clickthree();"></div>
<script>
var colorsthree = ["Black","Indigo","Black"];
function button_clickthree() {
    var box = document.getElementById("animatethree");
    var background_color = box.style.backgroundColor;
    var i = colorsthree.indexOf(background_color);
    if (i === colorstwo.length-1) {
        i = -1;
    }
    animatethree.style.backgroundColor = colorsthree[i+1];
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's quite a bit of invalid and repetitive code, so for simplicity, I just reworked the entire thing. I'll note some of the problems below.

Since there were so many changes made to the HTML, CSS and JS, I won't list them all, but will leave it to you to observe the differences.

```js
// Gather the colors and elements, and set a shared `i` to `0`
var colors = ["Blue", "Green", "Indigo"];
var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".animate");
var i = 0;

// Have a single function that makes the current element black and the next
// one a different color
function button_click() {
  elems[i].style.backgroundColor = "Black";

  if (++i === colors.length) {
    i = 0
  }

  elems[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
}
```

```css
#container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  background: Black;
}
.animate {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  left: 175px;
  position: absolute;
}
.animate:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0px;
  background-color: Blue;
}
.animate:nth-child(2) {
  top: 175px;
}
.animate:nth-child(3) {
  top: 350px;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <button onClick="button_click();">Change Colour</button>
</p>

<div id="container">
  <div class="animate"></div>
  <div class="animate"></div>
  <div class="animate"></div>
</div>
```

---

Note that there are other ways to do this too, like having each color set in the CSS, and then setting the `visibility` to `hidden` or `visible` with JavaScript.

Some of the general problems were:

- the same ID attribute used more than once
- an extra `<body>` tag
- lots of repeating CSS, JS and HTML that was able to be greatly reduced